# Resetting the cumulative sum when a condition is met in R

Tags: r, sum, reset, cumsum

So I have a table that looks like this currently:

```
data_wrong <- data.table(State = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "PA", "PA", "PA", 
"NJ", "NJ", "NJ"), Year = c("1973", "1974", "1975", "2005", "1992", "1993", 
"2001", "1930", "1931", "1932"), Consecutive_Yrs = c(1,2,3,1,1,6,1,1,9,10))
```

And I'd like it to look like this:

```
data <- data.table(State = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "PA", "PA", "PA", "NJ", 
"NJ", "NJ"), Year = c("1973", "1974", "1975", "2005", "1992", "1993", 
"2001", "1930", "1931", "1932"), Consecutive_Yrs = c(1,2,3,1,1,2,1,1,2,3))
```

This is the code I'm using right now to get my table:

```
data$diff <- NA

data <- data %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  arrange(State) %>%
  mutate(diff = Year - lag(Year, default = first(Year)))

data$Consecutive_Yrs <- 1

data$Consecutive_Yrs <- ifelse(data$diff == 1, cumsum(data$Consecutive_Yrs), 
1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Both answers I have received do not work with my version of R. Can someone please suggest and ideas for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As. it is a `data.table`, an option is to use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
data_wrong[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.numeric(Year)) > 1)), 
       .(State)][, Consecutive_Yrs := as.numeric(seq_len(.N)), .(State, grp)]
data_wrong
#    State Year Consecutive_Yrs grp
# 1:    NY 1973               1   1
# 2:    NY 1974               2   1
# 3:    NY 1975               3   1
# 4:    NY 2005               1   2
# 5:    PA 1992               1   1
# 6:    PA 1993               2   1
# 7:    PA 2001               1   2
# 8:    NJ 1930               1   1
# 9:    NJ 1931               2   1
#10:    NJ 1932               3   1
```

---

Or use `rowid`

```
data_wrong[, Consecutive_Yrs2 := rowid(rleid(as.numeric(Year) - 
        shift(as.numeric(Year), fill = as.numeric(Year[1])) >1)), .(State)]
```

Comment: I got this error: 
Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 16510 items of column 'Consecutive_Yrs' (recycled leaving remainder of 4 items).

Comment: Oh wait, I got an error but it actually ran and worked..is that ok?

Comment: @Sarah The first error is because you already have a 'Consecutive_Yrs' column n the dataset which is of type `numeric`.  The `seq_len(.N)` returns `integer`.  Either, convert it to `numeric` or create a new column name would solve it

Comment: @Sarah Can you please run the updated code on the fresh data created

Comment: I'm still getting that error. I changed all of my variables to numeric. But it's still outputting what I want.

Comment: @Sarah can you test the code on the example you showed.  It is working fine for me

Comment: @Sarah I updated with another option.  Please check if that works

Comment: It's saying could not find function "."

Comment: @Sarah Have you loadeed `library(data.table)` and what is the version of data.table

Comment: I'm using version 1.12.2 and yes I loaded it.

Comment: @Sarah I alsso have the same version on `R 3.6.0`.  Sorry, i can't reproduce the issue and the datasets also is the same as you already showed it

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to figure out how to do this because the solution below also is not working properly..

Comment: @Sarah What is the R version you havee

Comment: I'm on 3.4.2. I am unable to update unfortunately

Comment: @Sarah Okay, that may explain the issue

Comment: do you have any insight on how to fix the code the other person responded with to get it to work? It doesn't work for the 1 circumstance I explained below.